# How can I write these functions to use a forEach() statement?

Tags: javascript, jslint

How can write these (working) functions using `forEach()` methods:

```
function loadAudioMeterHistory(cell) {
    var peaks = new Array(4);

    for (var i = 0; i < peaks.length; i++) {
        var peak,
            age;

        peak = cell.getAttribute("data-peak-" + i);
        age  = cell.getAttribute("data-age-" + i);

        peaks[i] = new Peak(peak, age);
    }

    return peaks;
}
function setAudioMeterHistory(cell, peaks) {
    for (var i = 0; i < peaks.length; i++) {
        cell.setAttribute("data-peak-" + i, peaks[i].peak);
        cell.setAttribute("data-age-" + i,  peaks[i].age);
    }
}
```

My attempt was the following:

```
function loadAudioMeterHistory(cell) {
    "use strict";
    var peaks = new Array(4);

    peaks.forEach(function(item, index) {
        var p = cell.getAttribute("data-peak-" + index);
        var a = cell.getAttribute("data-age-" + index);

        item = new Peak(p, a);
    });

    return peaks;
}
function setAudioMeterHistory(cell, peaks) {
    "use strict";
    peaks.forEach(function(item, index) {
        cell.setAttribute("data-peak-" + index, item.peak);
        cell.setAttribute("data-age-"  + index, item.age);
    });
}
```

which, behaves differently, in that `peaks` is never properly created.  The savvy javascripter will undoubtedly recognise that I'm attempting to jslint.com my code.

The `Peak()` method (for brevity's sake) is simply:

```
function Peak(peak, age) {
    this.peak = peak;
    this.age  = age;
}
```

What gives?

Comment: A [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) would be better for `loadAudioMeterHistory`

Comment: `peaks.forEach` becomes `peaks.map` and `item = new Peak(p, a)` becomes `return new Peak(p, a)`

Comment: forEach/map does not loop over indexes when the value was not set. A simple console.log() would show the code not getting hit.

Comment: so... `var peaks = new Array(4).fill(null)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forEach` just iterates over a list but does not return anything. So use `map` instead and return the newly created object.

```
function loadAudioMeterHistory(cell) {
  "use strict";

  var peaks = [0, 1, 2, 3].map(function(item, index) {
    var p = cell.getAttribute("data-peak-" + index);
    var a = cell.getAttribute("data-age-" + index);

    return new Peak(p, a);
  });
}
```

One more problem is `peaks` is not available outside the scope of `loadAudioMeterHistory`. So have the function return that which can be passed into the next function call.

```
function loadAudioMeterHistory(cell) {
  "use strict";

  return [0, 1, 2, 3].map(function(item, index) {
    var p = cell.getAttribute("data-peak-" + index);
    var a = cell.getAttribute("data-age-" + index);

    return new Peak(p, a);
  });
}

function setAudioMeterHistory(cell) {
  "use strict";

  var peaks = loadAudioMeterHistory(cell);

  peaks.forEach(function(item, index) {
    cell.setAttribute("data-peak-" + index, item.peak);
    cell.setAttribute("data-age-" + index, item.age);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) whose second argument is a function to populate the array:

```
function loadAudioMeterHistory(cell) {
  return Array.from({ length: 4 }, (_, i) => {
    const peak = cell.getAttribute('data-peak-' + i);
    const age  = cell.getAttribute('data-age-' + i);
    return new Peak(peak, age);
  });
}
```

For the second function, use forEach() like this:

```
function setAudioMeterHistory(cell, peaks) {
  peaks.forEach(({ peak, age }) => {
    cell.setAttribute('date-peak-' + i, peak);
    cell.setAttribute('data-age-' + i, age);
  });
}
```